# Spring Webflux Rest Controller for image response correct return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive

I am creating a Spring WebFlux Controller that returns an image. I have tried this option below, based on similar questions.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/*")
public class ImageController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    protected void doGet(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
       try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
            DataBuffer imageData = response.bufferFactory().wrap(barr);
            //returns empty content in response
            //response.writeWith(Flux.just(imageData));
            //returns valid image
            response.writeWith(Flux.just(imageData)).block();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
```

The image is valid and I can also see that the DataBuffer has the bytes. However it is not sending the response back to the client.

The response to this service is successful (status 200), but the payload is empty (0 Bytes).

Can anyone identify the error here?

**[UPDATE]**

I got the Controller to return the image by adding the call to block:

```
response.writeWith(Flux.just(imageData)).block();
```

I also see that it works by calling subscribe():

```
response.writeWith(Flux.just(imageData)).subscribe();
```

What is the right approach for this type of controller? Is this equivalent to a flush() call on a Stream? Shouldn't the WebFlux framework block or flush the response object after the controller method is completed?

Similar questions:

[How to write messages to http body in Spring webflux WebExceptionHandlder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047645/how-to-write-messages-to-http-body-in-spring-webflux-webexceptionhandlder)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58351771/6352160

Comment: Dont ever block, as it will hurt performance very hard. Only subscribe if you are the final consumer. Dont return void, reactive function should never return void, instead return `Mono<Void>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I got this to work. It was a simple problem, but I was following the same approach used for traditional Spring MVC (to write the image as a byte stream into the servlet response).

```
 @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
 public Mono<DataBuffer> doGet(ServerHttpRequest request) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
        baos.close();
        byte[] barr = baos.toByteArray();
        DataBuffer imageData =  
           DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap(barr);
        return Mono.just(imageData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("An unknown IO error occurred while writing pixel", e);
    } 
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The WebFlux provides async processing along which can be utilized while file / byte data can be provided as stream.

If using `Netty` with WebFlux then it internally provides `DataBuffer` factory where a data file is split into the chunk (with given buffer size) and chunks are streamed on response.

```
    private val dataBufferFactory: DataBufferFactory = NettyDataBufferFactory(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)

     //The producer define the media type based on image type is available in MediaType class else Octet-Stream can be used, accept need to pass in request header
    @GetMapping(produces = [IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, IMAGE_PNG_VALUE, IMAGE_GIF_VALUE, APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE])
    fun imageStream(): Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> {
            val filename = "test.png"
            val bufferSize = 8192 //Define buffer size, number of Flux's elements = total file size / bufferSize
            val headers = HttpHeaders()
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(FILENAME, filename)
            val resource = ClassPathResource("$filename") //There are various implementations of Resource interface which can be used based on need
            Flux<DataBuffer> dataFlux = DataBufferUtils.read(resource, dataBufferFactory, bufferSize) //Important utility which converts the Resource object to Flux<DataBuffer>
            ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(idataFlux)
            .doOnSuccess { logger.debug("Stream request success") }
            .doOnError { logger.debug("Stream request error") }
    }
```

This makes performance faster as memory will be utilized based on defined buffer size instead of complete file read at once.

Apart from `DataBuffer` return, you can also return any implementation of spring core's `Resource` interface from controller method. For example:

```
ClassPathResource
FileSystemResource
InputStreamResource
```

There are many other implementation available with Spring for `Resource` interface.

The return type would be something like:
`Mono<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>>`

In `Resource` return types, the buffer size is managed by framework but data of resource will be streamed similar to what happens in DataBuffer implementation.