# How to reactively encode and render JPEG images?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to develop a Spring WebFlux application that encodes and renders JPEG images stored in the file system. I'm using ImageIO for encoding and trying to render the image using DataBuffer.

**RenderService.kt**

```
fun renderImage() : ResponseEntity<Mono<DataBuffer>> {
    
    val imageStream = FileInputStream("path/to/image")
    
    val os = ByteArrayOutputStream()`your text`
    val image = ImageIO.read(imageStream)

    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os)
    val ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os)
    val writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next()
    val writerParam = writer.defaultWriteParam
    writerParam.compressionMode = ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT
    writerParam.compressionQuality = 0.70f
    writer.output = ios

    try {
        writer.write(null, IIOImage(image, null, null), writerParam)
    } catch (internalError: InternalError) {
        throw IIOException("Internal Server Error due to Image Issue: ${internalError.message}")
    }
    
    val barr = os.toByteArray()
    val imageData: DataBuffer = DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap(barr)
    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
        .body(Mono.just(imageData))
}
```

**RenderController.kt**

```
fun renderImg() : ResponseEntity<Mono<DataBuffer>> {
    return imageService.renderImage()
}
```

After a request is hit, the response is:
`Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer] with preset Content-Type 'null']`

When I change the response type to ResponseEntity in the service and controller, the image renders correctly:

```
    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
        .body(os.toByteArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

To reactively encode and render JPEG images in a Spring WebFlux application, you should use a `Resource` to represent the image data and leverage Spring's built-in support for serving resources as responses. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. **Update the Service**:

   In your service, load the image into a `Resource` instead of a `DataBuffer`. You can use `FileSystemResource` to read the image from the file system.

   ```kotlin
   import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
   import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

   fun renderImage(): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
       val imageResource: Resource = FileSystemResource("path/to/image")

       if (imageResource.exists()) {
           return ResponseEntity
               .ok()
               .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
               .body(imageResource)
       } else {
           // Handle the case when the image does not exist
           return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Update the Controller**:

   In your controller, return the `ResponseEntity<Resource>` directly from the service method.

   ```kotlin
   @RestController
   class RenderController(private val imageService: RenderService) {

       @GetMapping("/render")
       fun renderImg(): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
           return imageService.renderImage()
       }
   }
   ```

With these changes, your Spring WebFlux application will serve the JPEG image as a resource, and Spring will handle the encoding and rendering of the image for you. This approach is more streamlined and leverages Spring's capabilities to serve resources efficiently.

Comment: Does this ensure that the image is streamed in chunks? I tried implementing another solution given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/75383550/22447148 but I faced the same issue. How is the code given here different from returning a Resource object?